# How to use Fade Scale of animations package for SnackBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-packages

In Readme of the [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) package, I can see the fade scale transition working not only for a modal popup like `AlertDialog` but also for non-modal `SnackBar`, but could not find any detailed documentation on it. Files in example and test directories don't have related code either.

It looks like the fade scale transition provides only [FadeScaleTransition](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/FadeScaleTransition-class.html) and [FadeScaleTransitionConfiguration](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/FadeScaleTransitionConfiguration-class.html); the former is for its (normal) child widget and the latter is for a modal dialog. SnackBar is neither of them, and I couldn't use it successfully although I tried in many ways.

Has anyone figured out how to use the package for SnackBar?